# ObjectBox subscription for new objects

Tags: objectbox

Is it possible to create a box subscription that will only trigger upon new objects being created in the box?

I can get a list of all objects in the box on a put, but I really only want to be informed of the new object that was created with the put.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently you can only listen for changes without any classification of the type. We'll keep that feature request in mind for future extensions.